# Custom global variable not working in function

Tags: php, functions, variables, globals

I've been stumped on this for a while and cannot for the life of me figure out why my function isn't able to reference my global variable.

```
$query_obj = get_queried_object();

if ( is_a($query_obj, 'WP_Term') ) {
    $my_base_url = get_term_link($query_obj);
} elseif ( is_a($query_obj, 'WP_Post') ) {
    $my_base_url = get_permalink();
} else {
    $my_base_url = null;
}

function getDropdown($args, $items, $all=false) {
    global $my_base_url;

    if (isset($_GET[$args])) {
         $check = $_GET[$args];
    } else {
        $check = null;
    }
    $output = '<ul class="dropdown ' . $args . '">';
    if ($all == true) {
        $output .= '<li class="' . ($check == null ? 'active' : null) . '"><a href="' . remove_query_arg( $args, add_query_arg( null, null ) ) . '">All</a></li>';
    }
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        $output .= '<li' . ($check == $value ? ' class="active"' : null) .'><a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( $args, $value ) ) . '">' . $key . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output . '<p>' . $my_base_url . '</p>';
}
```

The `return` at the bottom just has a paragraph tacked out to return the variable but it shows up blank. The only way I've been able to use the base URL was by using it as a function argument and passing it that way. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps all you need to do is call the `global` both when defining/setting the variable as well as when reading its value, e.g. `global $var; $var = 'foo';` in a function and `global $var; echo $var;` in another function. But your question is off-topic here and better suited at Stack Overflow..

Comment: @SallyCJ I think there was some confusion since I didn't include the one variable in my original code in the topic. $my_base_url is being defined and storing the URL correctly. I can echo it outside of the getDropdown function correctly but inside the function it doesn't show anything. It looks like defining ```global``` on the variable initially and in the function fixed it. Looking at other examples online it doesn't seem like you normally have to add ```global``` initially so it seems odd but at least it's working so thank you.

Comment: The "in a/another function" are just sample contexts. And you need to call `global` if you're not already in the global scope when setting the variable just as the sample contexts, i.e. two different functions. Alternatively, you can use the array notation: `$GLOBALS['var'] = 'foo'` and there'd be no need for the `global` call. But as I pointed, these "global" stuff are generic PHP programming and not WP-specific - WP does not do anything that would prevent one from reading/setting a global variable. And perhaps, it's better if you just pass the variable to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I try to use this code and for the if statments I had to put a global $query_obj before the code, I do not know if is the case.

```
global $query_obj;
if ( is_a($query_obj, 'WP_Term') ) {
    $my_base_url = get_term_link($query_obj);
} elseif ( is_a($query_obj, 'WP_Post') ) {
    $my_base_url = get_permalink();
} else {
    $my_base_url = null;
}
```

this seems to be working properly this way. In my wordpress only returns null. but the global variable $my_base_url is working fine when whe call $global $query_obj before the if's statments.

```
global $query_obj;
if ( is_a($query_obj, 'WP_Term') ) {
    $my_base_url = get_term_link($query_obj);
} elseif ( is_a($query_obj, 'WP_Post') ) {
    $my_base_url = get_permalink();
} else {
    $my_base_url = 'its null';
}
function ti(){
  global $my_base_url;
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($my_base_url);
  echo '</pre>';
}
ti();
```

Now to test the function I will need the $args , $items variables at least..

If you have the wp_debug set to true in wp_config.php this error should appear

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```